# Life cycle of dependency in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class named Group with virtual CPQ field (one to many with User class) and AllowedFeatures (many to many with Feature class).

I use lazy loading for entities but I don't understand why the dependency are null or throw an exception.

```
public List<Group> GetListGroups()
{
    using (var db = new DalContext())
    {
        return db.Groups.ToList();
    }
}
```

[image]

The goal of lazy loading is to create a proxy object of each related object but why these proxy are destroyed when leaving using ?

I really want to not use Include method because I have some objects with 4 levels of one to many relationship and I have to add 10 lines of include...

Comment: The point of "using" is to destroy everything created inside the "using" method.

Comment: Considerations of what to include shouldn't be inspired by typing effort. If you need the data, include/load them. Lazy loading requires the context to stay alive. And, BTW, the proxies aren't *destroyed*.

Comment: No other mean to do that ? Is there a full loading mode ?

Comment: @Matt Your answer is relevant and shouldn't be deleted. Lazy loading is clearly triggered in the method that consumes `GetListGroups`, so the context is disposed at that point.

Comment: *Is there a full loading mode* -- No there isn't. There are posts on including all navigation properties automatically but that requires custom code, and, obviously, should be handled with care.

Comment: @GertArnold I undeleted it, thanks for getting the relevance of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> [The using statement defines a scope at the end of which an object will be disposed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using)

Please, check [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) regarding `using` statement.

Documentation states following:

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects.

Comment: I know how using works !! I make a return in the using so if using disposed objects, the function will return nothing